# Collatz Sequence - Trying to fix a printed 'None' value

Tags: python

Complete beginner here, I'm currently reading through "Automate the Boring Stuff With Python" by Al Sweigert. I'm running into an issue where my program is returning a `None` value and I can't figure out how to change that.

I understand that at some point `collatz(number)` doesn't have a value, therefor `None` is returned- but I don't understand how to fix it. The book hasn't touched on `yield` yet. I've tried using `return` instead of `print` within the function, but I haven't been able to fix it.

```
def collatz(number):

    while number != 1:
        if number % 2 == 0:
            number = number // 2
            print(number)

        elif number % 2 == 1:
            number = 3 * number + 1
            print(number)

print('Enter number:')
try:
    number = int(input())
    print(collatz(number))

except ValueError:
        print ('Please enter an integer.')
```

Comment: `collatz` itself is printing the number, not returning it. `print(collatz(number))` just prints the `None` returned implicitly due to the lack of a `return` statement. Don't call `print` when you call `collatz`.

Comment: Got it, I understand now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @chepner proposed you need to remove the print statement which is enclosing your collatz(number) call. The correct code would look like

```
def collatz(number):

    while number != 1:
        if number % 2 == 0:
            number = number // 2
            print(number)

        elif number % 2 == 1:
            number = 3 * number + 1
            print(number)

print('Enter number:')
try:
    number = int(input())
    collatz(number)

except ValueError:
        print ('Please enter an integer.')
```